# Unity Error, Cannot initialize non-default texture with negative or zero width

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development, textmeshpro

As I am trying to run my game, it displays the following error:

> Unity Error,  Cannot initialize non-default texture with negative or zero width,
> UnityEngine.Texture2D:Resize (int,int,UnityEngine.TextureFormat,bool)
> TMPro.TMP_FontAsset:ClearAtlasTextures (bool) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0.6/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_FontAsset.cs:2846)

And when I click on it, it directs me to the TMP code line:

```
if (setAtlasSizeToZero)
            {
                texture.Resize(0, 0, TextureFormat.Alpha8, false);
            }
```

I am not sure what to do, since I cannot modify this code.

I think It has to do with the TextMeshPro version, I tried updating it, but the pre version is not visible, I tried installing it, it doesn't work, Any alternative solution?

Comment: reimport TMP essential resources from window menu solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project copy Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.TextMeshPro.dll from it to the problem project and the problem should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

DON'T: File > Build and Run

DO: File > Build Settings > Build

My error messages were similar to the err msg from the Question

they related to TMPro